# Is there any method to justify text in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, alignment, text-justify

I need to add a text field in my unity scene with the justified alignment. But the problem is that I'm not getting any syntax of the method to justify the text in unity 2D. Need your help!

Comment: Hi, I think I can help you but I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you try to describe a bit more, perhaps with screenshots, of what you wish to accomplish?

Comment: Meanwhile, if you have a look at your text component, there are icons for justifying the text. First option under "*Paragraph*": https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/37800-text.png

Comment: Thank you @Maakep for the response, but those icons are for left, right and center alignment. And the other three icons on the right are for the top, bottom and center alignment.  I'm gonna attach a picture from one of my scenes. As there is a paragraph which is right aligned and i want it to be with justifying alignment(means equal from both side). Image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w6hWjwxb_cO5NWqPYoRNoPa4hcMfQSyb/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Just use TextMeshPro for 2d [TextMeshPro inspector settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiSth.jpg)
There is the link to text mesh pro manual [TextMesh Pro Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0/manual/index.html)